# Automorphisms $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb R$ as ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

What are the automorphisms $(\mathbb R, 0, 1, +, \cdot, \leq)\to (\mathbb R, 0, 1, +, \cdot, \leq)$ and how many are there?

Comment: The identity? That would be quite nice. What's the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well known theorem: the only field automorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is the identity. You don't even need to assume it respects the order, because it's a consequence of being a field automorphism.

Indeed, $f(x^2)=f(x)^2>0$, for every $x\ne0$. Since every positive element is a square, if $x>y$ we have $f(x-y)>0$, so $f(x)>f(y)$.

Then it's easy to prove that $f(m/n)=m/n$, for every rational $m/n$ ($m,n$ integers, $n\ne0$).

Finish by proving that $f$ has to be continuous with respect to the usual metric.

Comment: $f(x^2) = f(x)^2$

Comment: From the strict monotonicity of $f$ and from $f(q)=q$ for all  $q \in \mathbb Q$ we have, for every $x,$  that  $\mathbb Q\cap (x,\infty)=\mathbb Q\cap (f(x),\infty) ,$  so $f(x)=x.$